# How can I toggle a div and simulateously hide previously toggled divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide, submenu

When I click on any menu item the sub menu for that item shows. Which is great. Then when I click on any other menu item the first box/sub menu disappears and a new sub menu appears, which is also great. The problem is that the remaining/last sub menu does not go away. I want to be able to click on any of the menu items and make the remaining/last sub menu hide.

my url: http://arabic001.com

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('.menu').click(function()  {

       $('.subNav').hide();
          $(this).next().toggle('slow');


        });

        })
```

Comment: Not quite following you here.  What you want is: menu.click(<close any previously opened submenu; open new submenu>)  but you also want: menu.click(<close any previous submenu; end;>).  You can't have both.  Maybe you want this: menu.click(<if any submenu open, close it; else open this submenu>).  Is that what you want? It's doable but that means the user will have to click twice to switch from one submenu to another, which is ugly, IMO.

Comment: I'm with @smendola; I have no idea what's being asked here.

Comment: you are right I don't want the user to click twice.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this yesterday...

When I toggle something open I add a new class to the element, then when a new item is toggled, you can use the class you added as the selector to close the open item.

```
    $("#btn_toggle_transcript").on("click",
            function(){
                closeOpen("#transcript_container");
                $("#transcript_container").slideToggle(1000);
                $("#transcript_container").addClass('ToggleOpen');
            }
    );

function closeOpen(ignore){
    if(ignore!=''){
                $(".ToggleOpen:not('"+ignore+"')").slideUp(500);
                $(".ToggleOpen:not('"+ignore+"')").removeClass('ToggleOpen');
            }else{
                $(".ToggleOpen").slideUp(500);
                $(".ToggleOpen").removeClass('ToggleOpen');
            }    }
```

UPDATE: I removed the "ignore" bit I had in there.  It was superfluous.  This works great for me.  I also changed the binding method to use the $(selector).on("event",callback) format.

UPDATE:  Oops!  I DID need that ignore in there.  Otherwise the closing action would bounce open again. :(